# Tracing source of error in difflib due to very different string comparison

Tags: python, pandas, difflib

I am processing a large amount of text data (11m rows), and get the error below. Is there a way I can trace the row of text that's causing this error?

My code:

```
from difflib import ndiff # find differences between strings
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm # add a timer to pandas apply()
tqdm.pandas() # start timer

# read in all keystrokes
dat = pd.read_csv("all_ks_dat_good.csv", delimiter="|",
                  encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# use the ndiff function to find additions to strings, i.e. c[0]=='+'
def diff(x):
    s1 = str(x['last_text'])
    s2 = str(x['scrubbed_text'])
    l = [c[-1] for c in ndiff(s1, s2) if c[0] == '+']
    return ''.join(l)

# add a column for the additional keystrokes, 
# using tqdm's progress_apply() instead of apply()
dat['add_ks'] = dat.progress_apply(diff, axis=1)

dat.to_csv('all_ks_word_dat.csv', sep="|", encoding="utf-8")
```

The abridged error:

```
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 997, in _fancy_helper
    yield from g
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 985, in _fancy_replace
    yield from self._fancy_helper(a, best_i+1, ahi, b, best_j+1, bhi)
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 997, in _fancy_helper
    yield from g
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 915, in _fancy_replace
    cruncher = SequenceMatcher(self.charjunk)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.set_seqs(a, b)
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 194, in set_seqs
    self.set_seq2(b)
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 248, in set_seq2
    self.__chain_b()
  File "/home/goodkindan/.conda/envs/ks0/lib/python3.11/difflib.py", line 288, in __chain_b
    for elt in b2j.keys():
```

Comment: The traceback looks incomplete.

Comment: It's 1000s (millions?) of lines long. It keeps repeating the first two lines, but I can't scroll to the top of it. That's why I'm trying to isolate the line of input text that's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes, you could try to iterate on the dataframe with Pandas [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and print the row causing the error, like this:

```py
for _, row in dat.iterrows():
    try:
        diff(row)
    except Exception:
        print(row)
```